# How to apply this KNN code to my data set?

Tags: pandas, numpy, machine-learning, knn

I have this KNN code and I want to apply this to my dataframe. It has 2 columns: one is the X and the other is the Y. How to apply it? Do I need to put them in `generate_data`? I don't know to connect them. (Are they already connected?)

```
import pandas as pd
from pyod.models.knn import KNN
from pyod.utils.data import generate_data
from pyod.utils.data import evaluate_print
from pyod.utils.example import visualize

# Import data
AAPL= pd.read_csv('AAPL.csv', header=0, squeeze=True)

# Independent variables - Matrix
X = AAPL.iloc[:,1].squeeze()

# Dependent variables - vector
Y = AAPL.iloc[:,2].squeeze()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    contamination = 0.1  # percentage of outliers
    n_train = 200  # number of training points
    n_test = 100  # number of testing points

    # Generate sample data
    X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = \
        generate_data(n_train=n_train,
                      n_test=n_test,
                      n_features=2,
                      contamination=contamination,
                      random_state=42)

    # train kNN detector
    clf_name = 'KNN'
    clf = KNN()
    clf.fit(X_train)

    # get the prediction labels and outlier scores of the training data
    y_train_pred = clf.labels_  # binary labels (0: inliers, 1: outliers)
    y_train_scores = clf.decision_scores_  # raw outlier scores

    # get the prediction on the test data
    y_test_pred = clf.predict(X_test)  # outlier labels (0 or 1)
    y_test_scores = clf.decision_function(X_test)  # outlier scores

    # evaluate and print the results
    print("\nOn Training Data:")
    evaluate_print(clf_name, y_train, y_train_scores)
    print("\nOn Test Data:")
    evaluate_print(clf_name, y_test, y_test_scores)

    # visualize the results
    visualize(clf_name, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, y_train_pred,
              y_test_pred, show_figure=True, save_figure=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `generate_data()` if you have your own data. It's just for generating example data.

If you only have one feature (one column in `X`) then you will need to pass it to the `fit()` method as `np.atleast_2d(X)`, because the input data `X` must be a 2-D matrix (one row per record, one column per feature). You're only using one column, so it will be 1-D. From [the docs](https://pyod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyod.models.html#module-pyod.models.knn):

> **X** (*numpy array of shape (n_samples, n_features)*) – The input samples.

If you want to use training and validation datasets (recommended), you'll need to split your data somehow. For example, you could use 400 rows for training and 100 rows for validation. Or, if `pyod` doesn't give you a tool for splitting randomly, consider using something like `sklearn.preprocessing.train_test_split()`.